# How do I prevent find from printing .git folders?

Tags: find

I have a `find` command that I run to find files whose names contain `foo`.

I want to skip the `.git` directory. The command below works **except** it prints an
annoying `.git` any time it skips a `.git` directory:

```
find . ( -name .git ) -prune -o -name '*foo*'
```

How can I prevent the skipped `.git` directories from 
printing to the standard output?

Comment: the syntax `( -name .git )` makes no sense

Comment: Right -- I think it should be \\( -name .git \\), correct?

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314643/how-can-i-get-find-to-ignore-svn-directories) and replace "svn" with "git".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find . -name '*foo*' | grep -v '\.git'
```

This will still traverse into the .git directories, but won't display them. Or you can combine with your version:

```
find . ( -name .git ) -prune -o -name '*foo*' | grep -v '\.git'
```

You can also do it without grep:

```
find . ( -name .git ) -prune -printf '' -o -name '*foo*' -print
```

Comment: Okay -- I found that I don't have to put the -printf '' -- I only have to put the -print on the back of the command!

For example, this works:
find . \( -name .git \) -prune -o -name '*foo*' -print

Thanks!

Comment: Using a grep after find is a bad trick for many reasons. Consider using the builtin options in find for filtering

Comment: As @ToniHomedesiSaun said, using `grep` is a poor solution - not least because the example you give will ignore all files matching the string `.git` - not just directories. The pure `find` is also not specific to directories, so will ignore files named `.git`

Comment: `find . ( -name .git ) -prune -false -o -name '*foo*'` works for me

Answer (score 10):

So just for better visibility:

```
find -name '.git*' -prune -o -name '*foo*' -print
```

This also omits .gitignore files; note the trailing **-print** to omit printing, -prune stops descending into it but without -print prints it nevertheless. Twisted C;

Comment: Here's how to find directories:   find . -name '.git\*' -prune -o -name '\*foo\*' -maxdepth 4 -type d -print

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -not -wholename "./.git*" -name "*foo*"
```

or, more strictly, if you don't want to see .git/ but do want to search in other dirs whose name also begins with .git (`.git-foo/bar/...`)

```
find . -not -wholename "./.git" -not -wholename "./.git/*" -name "*foo*"
```

If your .git/ directories may not always necessarily be located at the top-level of your search directory, you will want to use `-not -wholename ".*/.git"` and `-not -wholename ".*/.git/*"`.

A bit odder but more efficient because it prunes the whole `.git` dir:

```
find . -not \( -wholename "./.git" -prune \) -name "*foo*"
```