# How do you Tar an svn directory and filter out all the .svn files?

Tags: svn, filter, tar

I'm trying to create a tar file for deployment of some code but I dont want all the .svn files being deployed.

How can I filter these out? They're in multiple directories...

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
tar --exclude=.svn -z -c -v -f mytarball.tar.gz mydir/
```

Comment: You can also use '--exclude-vcs'

Comment: Very nice, gzipped a package down from 91 to 54MB :)

Comment: Note that --exclude-vcs is only present in tar 1.28 and above.

Answer (score 31):

If you have a tar version 1.28 or later, try

`tar --exclude-vcs`

It can be used to backup directories containing:

- a single svn repo
- multiple svn repos
- no svn repos

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/exclude.html):

> ‘--exclude-vcs’ 
>   Exclude files and directories used by following version control systems: ‘CVS’, ‘RCS’, ‘SCCS’, ‘SVN’, ‘Arch’,‘Bazaar’, ‘Mercurial’, and ‘Darcs’.

#### Note:

For some versions of tar, `--exclude-vcs` must be the first argument.

Comment: At least on Cygwin, SVN files are still included while using this flag

Comment: It's only present in tar 1.28 and above.

Comment: @jmlarson I had the same issue with 1.29 on Ubuntu 18.04. I had to change around the _order_ of the options and I got it to work. Notably, putting `--exclude-vcs` _first,_ before all my other options, worked.

Answer (score 4):

use `svn export` command to make a clean copy of the local sandbox.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html

```
svn export [-r REV] URL [PATH]

svn export PATH1 PATH2
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the svn Export function to get a clean version of the files without the .svn folders.

Do this in a different location than your working copy.

Answer (score 2):

Approach (1)

Expanding on the answer in this thread that cites the SVN Book's solution  (which is SVN-centric) , I give this example:

c:>   **svn export -r rrev  https:/A_SERVER/svn/A_REPO/A_PROJECT/    c:\tmp\arepo--aproject--rrev\**

c:\tmp\arepo--aproject--rrev>   **tar   zcvf   arepo--aproject--rrev.tar.gz   ***

Approach (2)

There is also another a long and informative thread found at:

[How can I get `find` to ignore .svn directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314643/how-can-i-get-find-to-ignore-svn-directories)

This different,  discussion strikes me a  mostly find-centric and tar-centric . (Both interesting topics in their own right)

I found it best to use solution (1) above.  For me.

I mostly got the other "find--from--filtered-STDIN-way" to work, but not consistently given complexities and vagaries of using all of  DOS, Linux, find-variants, xargs,  etc.

Comment: agree.. For a fresh checkout, (1) is the best way. But say, this is after a "build" and you want to package things in the directory where you ran the build steps, (2) is a good solution (since some generated or compiled content is not in svn)..