# Can ack find files based on filename only?

Tags: filenames, ack

Using [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) (sometimes packaged as ack-grep) I know that I can find *paths* that contain a specific string by doing:
`ack -g somestring`

But what if I only want files which have "somestring" in their *filenames*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `find` utility. Something like this:

```
find /path/to/look/in -name '*somestring*' -print
```

On some systems, if you omit the path, current directory is used. On other systems you can't omit it, just use `.` for current directory instead.

Also, read `man find` for many other options.

Comment: This is the answer.  Unless you're using the filetype detection features of ack, `find` is the way to go.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Question is about how to do it with ack. There is at least one use case, where this is useless - consider someone using ack on windows - there your answer won't work.

Answer (score 50):

I agree find is the way to go, but you could also easily do it with ack:

```
ack -f | ack "string"
```

Here, "ack -f" recursively lists all the files it would search; pipe that to the second ack command to search through that.
  ack -f does have the advantage of skipping over binaries and directories even without any more arguments; often, then a "find" command could be replaced by a much shorter "ack" command.

Comment: Find is faster.

Comment: ack -f | rg "string"

Comment: This answer would include matches in the path (directory names, which the question wanted to exclude) as well as in the filename.

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to use `ack` to find all files that have `somestring` in their basename, just add `[^/]*$` to the regex, e.g.,

```
ack -g somestring[^/]*$
```

Unfortunately, `--color` will show the match from `somestring` to the end of the filename; but it is possible to do what you asked for using `ack`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, or else I'd add this to @dmedvinsky's answer above. You may want to combine his approach with @whaley's [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286414/2491761) in order to filter out `.svn` files:

```
find /path/to/look/in -not -iwholename '*.svn*' -name '*somestring*' -print
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by 'Jeffrey Aguilera' should be marked as the correct answer. Along with the `-g` option, the `-w` option comes in pretty handy. In the invocation below, I am interested in find the names of all files and directories that have '001':

```bash
ack -w '001' -g
```

```bash
pghack/001.src/index.js
pghack/001.src/stl.js
migrations/001-initial.sql
...
expeditions/001/chords.mjs
expeditions/001/chords.html
expeditions/001/README.md
```

Resorting to `find` command is unnecessary and doesn't answer the OP's question, IMO.

Answer (score -2):

this works for me, ack -all "somestring" where as ack --all "somestring" will search all files  that contain that string.  ack "somestring" will only search files with that string.  if you wanted to add some file type to search permanently like ruby files or you can create .ackrc file in your home directory, add the fallowing line --type-add=ruby=.haml,.rake,.rsel .  JOsH

Comment: This appears to search file contents. That's not what the question asked for.