# Linux find file names with given string recursively

Tags: linux, string, find

I'm on Ubuntu, and I'd like to find all files in the current directory and subdirectories whose name contains the string "John". I know that `grep` can match the content of the files, but I have no idea how to use it with file names.

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Use the [find](https://www.mankier.com/1/find) command,

```
find . -type f -name "*John*"
```

Comment: Creating a custom bash script with `#!/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]; then echo "Error: Specify pattern for search"; else /usr/bin/find . -type f -name "*$1*"; fi

` would let you just run `F search-string` as a perfect shortcut

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - nice, but `[ -z "$1" ]` would be a bit better.

Comment: @Joe Ah, right. You mean in case a path has spaces? But here we only check for existence of $1 space would make $2 appear and that's it. You mean it's theoretically better, right?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - Actually, I was wrong. If $1 is null then the test becomes `if [ -z ]`. I thought that would be a syntax error, but it works. I can simplify some of my code from now on.

Comment: The "locate" command is orders of magnitude faster and easier to use with grep.  See @thucnguyen 's answer.

Answer (score 7):

The `find` command will take long time because it scans real files in file system.

The quickest way is using `locate` command, which will give result immediately:

```
locate "John"
```

If the command is not found, you need to install `mlocate` package and run `updatedb` command first to prepare the search database for the first time.

More detail here: https://medium.com/@thucnc/the-fastest-way-to-find-files-by-filename-mlocate-locate-commands-55bf40b297ab

Answer (score 4):

This is a very simple solution using the `tree` command in the directory you want to search for. `-f` shows the full file path and `|` is used to pipe the output of tree to `grep` to find the file containing the string `filename` in the name.

```
tree -f | grep filename
```

Answer (score 1):

use ack its simple.
just type `ack <string to be searched>`

Comment: It seems this will also include all _paths_ containing the search text, not just files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698867/can-ack-find-files-based-on-filename-only