# PhantomJs doesn't work on my web hosting

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs, web-hosting

I installed PhantomJS on my local web server (MAMP) and had no any problems with it, but when i uploaded my site folder on my web hosting, it wrote me the next message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'JonnyW\PhantomJs\Exception\ProcedureFailedException' with message 'Error when executing PhantomJs procedure "default" - File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs' in /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php:132 Stack trace: #0 /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Client.php(170): JonnyW\PhantomJs\Procedure\Procedure->run(Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Request), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Response)) #1 /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/index.php(81): JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client->send(Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Request), Object(JonnyW\PhantomJs\Message\Response)) #2 {main} thrown in /home/gorecky/hotshoppingdeals.net/omlife/vendor/jonnyw/php-phantomjs/src/JonnyW/PhantomJs/Procedure/Procedure.php on line 132

What can be a reason of this fatal problem?

My code used in index.php is:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

  $client = \JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client::getInstance();
  $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest($link, 'GET');
  $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
  $client->send($request, $response); 
  $html = $response->getContent();
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: > *File does not exist or is not executable: bin/phantomjs*. So, does this file exist? Is it executable?

Comment: @pawel Sorry for such question, maybe i don't understand smth) All i've done - was copying my project folder from local disk to my web hosting folder... On my local server Phantom works without any problems...

Comment: Try running `chmod +x bin/phantomjs`

Comment: @AlexanderM. i'm sorry, where should i do this?))

Comment: Probably it is a permissions issue. Check that php has correct permissions and required file is executable.

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko well, basically you should `cd` to a folder with `phantomjs` file and execute `chmod +x phantomjs` there, so you should find where the `phantomjs` is.  In order to find, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13131063/2044039

Comment: @AlexanderM. Thank you for answer, i've made what you said... and 

sh-3.2# ls
.DS_Store 
composer.json 
geo_ip.dat 
index.php vendor
.htaccess 
composer.lock 
geo_ip.php
main.js
bin  
composer.phar 
img  
styles.css
sh-3.2# chmod +x phantomjs
chmod: phantomjs: No such file or directory

Comment: i'm sorry, it seems that enough : sh-3.2# chmod +x phantomjs chmod: phantomjs: No such file or directory

Comment: What does `find ~ -type f -name "phantomjs"` give to you?

Comment: @AlexanderM. gives nothing, returns empty line(

Comment: @ArtyomSosonko have you actually dwnloaded and installed phantomjs? Here's an instruction how to get php-phantom up and running http://stackoverflow.com/a/20216210/2044039

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it for few hours) my local MAMP project had phantom installed with the help of composer, like symphony too... So the first think was to install phantom via official package)