# Recursively find all files containing 'string.txt' in file name

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to recursively search for all files and sub-directories within a directory with sub string within file name as 'string.txt'

My command:

```
   cd /home/abcd/dir
   grep -R "*rate-trace.txt" | wc -l
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248761/find-files-containing-string-in-file-name-and-different-string-within-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/608639), [Linux find file names with given string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13131048/608639), [Find all files with name containing string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11328988/608639), [How do I find all files containing specific text on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810/608639), etc.

Comment: @Inian, this is not realy the correct duplicate. This one is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard

Answer (score 6):

`grep` is searching the file's content.

Use `find` command instead:

```
find /home/abcd/dir -type f -name "*rate-trace.txt" | wc -l
```

OR

```
cd /home/abcd/dir
find . -type f -name "*rate-trace.txt" | wc -l
```