# How to glob all files with an extension in a directory and its subdirectories?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, glob

This feels like it must have an obvious answer, but I haven't yet found one.

Consider this file structure:

```
A.tsx
B.tsx
dist/C.tsx
dist/D.tsx
src/E.tsx
src/F.tsx
src/G.js
src/component/H.tsx
src/component/I.tsx
src/component/J.js
```

I want to list all `.tsx` files in the directory `src` and all of its descendants.

This lists all `.tsx` files in `src` but not its descendants:

```
ls src/*.tsx
```

This lists all `.tsx` files in `src`'s descendants, but not `src` itself:

```
ls src/**/*.tsx
```

Is there a way to glob all `.tsx` files in `src` *and* its descendants in one pattern?

Comment: What is the output of `shopt | grep globstar` ? It have to be enabled.

Comment: It doesn't return anything. FWIW I'm on a Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: `**` need `globstar` enabled. Yes, MacOs matters. You can install a newer bash with `homebrew install bash` because you seems to have a very old version < 3.* We are now at bash 5.2.*

Comment: `homebrew` projet's command is `brew`, so `brew install bash`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905054/how-can-i-recursively-find-all-files-in-current-and-subfolders-based-on-wildcard)

Comment: Also see [Recursively look for files with a specific extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5927369/4154375) and [Linux find file names with given string recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13131048/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure the `globstar` option is enabled, or else `**` is just interpreted as two adjacent `*` patterns, each of which will match 0 or more characters, so it's equivalent to `src/*/*.tex`, which must match *some* directory under `src`.

```
shopt -s globstar
ls src/**/*.tex
```

should work.

Note that you need `bash` 4 or later to use `globstar`. If you are using the system-provided `bash` on macOS (which is version 3.2), you'll need to install a recent version of `bash` yourself. (Or switch to `zsh`.)

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `ls src/**/*.tsx src/*.tsx`

Comment: Thanks, that certainly works, but there isn't a way to do it in one pattern?