# Use find command but exclude files in two directories

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I want to find files that end with `_peaks.bed`, but exclude files in the `tmp` and `scripts` folders.

My command is like this:

```
 find . -type f \( -name "*_peaks.bed" ! -name "*tmp*" ! -name "*scripts*" \)
```

But it didn't work. The files in `tmp` and `script` folder will still be displayed.

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 228, accepted):

Here's how you can specify that with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*_peaks.bed" ! -path "./tmp/*" ! -path "./scripts/*"
```

**Explanation:**

- `find .` - Start find from current working directory (recursively by default)
- `-type f` - Specify to `find` that you only want files in the results
- `-name "*_peaks.bed"` - Look for files with the name ending in `_peaks.bed`
- `! -path "./tmp/*"` - Exclude all results whose path starts with `./tmp/`
- `! -path "./scripts/*"` - Also exclude all results whose path starts with `./scripts/`

**Testing the Solution:**

```
$ mkdir a b c d e
$ touch a/1 b/2 c/3 d/4 e/5 e/a e/b
$ find . -type f ! -path "./a/*" ! -path "./b/*"

./d/4
./c/3
./e/a
./e/b
./e/5
```

You were pretty close, the `-name` option only considers the basename, where as `-path` considers the entire path =)

Comment: This uses a number of extension in GNU `find`, but since the question is tagged Linux, that is not a problem.  Good answer.

Comment: A short note: if you use `.` at your initial find prompt, you have to use it in each path you exclude.  The path matching is pretty strict, it doesn't do fuzzy searching.  So if you use `find / -type f -name *.bed" ! -path "./tmp/"` its not going to work.  you need to have `! -path "/tmp"` to make it happy.

Comment: Important to note that the * is important. `$ ! -path "./directory/*"`

Comment: According to the man pages: "To ignore a whole directory tree, use `-prune` rather than checking every file in the tree." If your excluded directories run very deep or has tons of files and you care about performance, then use the `-prune` option instead.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt your solution for a variable exclusion list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157332/build-directory-exclusion-list-programmatically-for-find-command-bash) but having no luck

Answer (score 18):

Use

```
find \( -path "./tmp" -o -path "./scripts" \) -prune -o  -name "*_peaks.bed" -print
```

or

```
find \( -path "./tmp" -o -path "./scripts" \) -prune -false -o  -name "*_peaks.bed"
```

or

```
find \( -path "./tmp" -path "./scripts" \) ! -prune -o  -name "*_peaks.bed"
```

The order is important. It evaluates from left to right.
Always begin with the path exclusion.

## Explanation

Do not use `-not` (or `!`) to exclude whole directory. Use `-prune`.
As explained in the manual:

```
−prune    The primary shall always evaluate as  true;  it
          shall  cause  find  not  to descend the current
          pathname if it is a directory.  If  the  −depth
          primary  is specified, the −prune primary shall
          have no effect.
```

and in the GNU find manual:

```
-path pattern
              [...]
              To ignore  a  whole
              directory  tree,  use  -prune rather than checking
              every file in the tree.
```

Indeed, if you use `-not -path "./pathname"`,
find will evaluate the expression for each node under `"./pathname"`.

find expressions are just condition evaluation.

- `\( \)` - groups operation (you can use `-path "./tmp" -prune -o -path "./scripts" -prune -o`, but it is more verbose).
- `-path "./script" -prune` - if `-path` returns true and is a directory, return true for that directory and do **not** descend into it.
- `-path "./script" ! -prune` - it evaluates as `(-path "./script") AND (! -prune)`. It revert the "always true" of prune to always false. It avoids printing `"./script"` as a match.
- `-path "./script" -prune -false` - since `-prune` always returns true, you can follow it with `-false` to do the same than `!`.
- `-o` - OR operator. If no operator is specified between two expressions, it defaults to AND operator.

Hence, `\( -path "./tmp" -o -path "./scripts" \) -prune -o -name "*_peaks.bed" -print` is expanded to:

```
[ (-path "./tmp" OR -path "./script") AND -prune ] OR ( -name "*_peaks.bed" AND print )
```

The print is important here because without it is expanded to:

```
{ [ (-path "./tmp" OR -path "./script" )  AND -prune ]  OR (-name "*_peaks.bed" ) } AND print
```

`-print` is added by find - that is why most of the time, you do not need to add it in you expression. And since `-prune` returns true, it will print "./script" and "./tmp".

It is not necessary in the others because we switched `-prune` to always return false.

Hint: You can use `find -D opt expr 2>&1 1>/dev/null` to see how it is optimized and expanded,
`find -D search expr 2>&1 1>/dev/null` to see which path is checked.

Comment: I've spent a couple of hours trying to find the answer to the same question, and I also wanted to understand what I was doing instead of just copying someones statement. This is definitely the best explanation I found. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `"./tmp"` and `"/.scripts"` only work if they're a direct child of the current directory. Use `"*/tmp"` and `"*/scripts"` to make it also works if they're in subdirectories (recursive).

Comment: @MImamPratama You can use `\(-name tmp -or -name scripts\)` for those cases

Answer (score 8):

Here is one way you could do it...

```
find . -type f -name "*_peaks.bed" | egrep -v "^(./tmp/|./scripts/)"
```

Comment: This has the merit of working with any version of `find`, rather than only with GNU `find`.  However, the question is tagged Linux so that is not critical.

Answer (score 1):

for me, this solution didn't worked on a command exec with find, don't really know why, so my solution is

```
find . -type f -path "./a/*" -prune -o -path "./b/*" -prune -o -exec gzip -f -v {} \;
```

**Explanation:** same as sampson-chen one with the additions of

-prune - ignore the proceding path of ...

-o - Then if no match print the results, (prune the directories and print the remaining results)

```
18:12 $ mkdir a b c d e
18:13 $ touch a/1 b/2 c/3 d/4 e/5 e/a e/b
18:13 $ find . -type f -path "./a/*" -prune -o -path "./b/*" -prune -o -exec gzip -f -v {} \;

gzip: . is a directory -- ignored
gzip: ./a is a directory -- ignored
gzip: ./b is a directory -- ignored
gzip: ./c is a directory -- ignored
./c/3:    0.0% -- replaced with ./c/3.gz
gzip: ./d is a directory -- ignored
./d/4:    0.0% -- replaced with ./d/4.gz
gzip: ./e is a directory -- ignored
./e/5:    0.0% -- replaced with ./e/5.gz
./e/a:    0.0% -- replaced with ./e/a.gz
./e/b:    0.0% -- replaced with ./e/b.gz
```

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work, but this works. Using prune, `find . -path ./scripts -prune -name '*_peaks.bed' -type f`. Not sure how to exclude multiple directories. This also lists the top level excluded directory even though `type` is specified. Excluding via Grep seems more straightforward unless you want to use prune to speed up the find operation.

Comment: I had trouble excluding multiple directories, too, but comments above gave me an answer that worked.  I use multiple instances of '-not -path' and in each path expression I include the full prefix as used in the first parameter to 'find' and end each with an asterisk (and escape any dots).

Answer (score 1):

**You can try below:**

```
find ./ ! \( -path ./tmp -prune \) ! \( -path ./scripts -prune \) -type f -name '*_peaks.bed'
```

Comment: On an old question like that (4 years!) you want to explain why this new answer is better or different, not just "dump" code.

Answer (score 1):

With these explanations you meet your objective and **many others**. Just join each part as you want to do.

MODEL

```
find ./\
 -iname "some_arg" -type f\ # File(s) that you want to find at any hierarchical level.
 ! -iname "some_arg" -type f\ # File(s) NOT to be found on any hirearchic level (exclude).
 ! -path "./file_name"\ # File(s) NOT to be found at this hirearchic level (exclude).
 ! -path "./folder_name/*"\ # Folder(s) NOT to be found on this Hirearchic level (exclude).
 -exec grep -IiFl 'text_content' -- {} \; # Text search in the content of the found file(s) being case insensitive ("-i") and excluding binaries ("-I").
```

EXAMPLE

```
find ./\
 -iname "*" -type f\
 ! -iname "*pyc" -type f\
 ! -path "./.gitignore"\
 ! -path "./build/*"\
 ! -path "./__pycache__/*"\
 ! -path "./.vscode/*"\
 ! -path "./.git/*"\
 -exec grep -IiFl 'title="Brazil - Country of the Future",' -- {} \;
```

**Thanks!**

[**Ref(s).:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73938/61742 ]

---

**EXTRA:**

You can use the commands above together with your favorite editor and analyze the contents of the files found, for example...

```
vim -p $(find ./\
 -iname "*" -type f\
 ! -iname "*pyc" -type f\
 ! -path "./.gitignore"\
 ! -path "./build/*"\
 ! -path "./__pycache__/*"\
 ! -path "./.vscode/*"\
 ! -path "./.git/*"\
 -exec grep -IiFl 'title="Brazil - Country of the Future",' -- {} \;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
find . \( -type f -name \*_peaks.bed -print \) -or \( -type d -and \( -name tmp -or -name scripts \) -and -prune \)
```

and don't be too surprised if I got it a bit wrong.  If the goal is an exec (instead of print), just substitute it in place.