# Exclude directories with a certain prefix using find

Tags: macos, bash, unix

Provided I'm not missing something that should be obvious, the OSX version of bash is different from Linux here, because I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132210/use-find-command-but-exclude-files-in-two-directories) would provide all I needed to know. It didn't.

I'm trying to use **`find`** to find all directories that do not begin with "." (Mac OS X uses the .-prefix for hidden folders, e.g., /volumes/OD/.Trashes). I want to pipe all the non-hidden directories to rysnc to periodically mirror two local directories.

I tested to make sure I'm using find correctly with this code here:

```
find /volumes/OD -type d -iname ".*"
```

It finds the directories:

```
/volumes/OD/.Trashes
/volumes/OD/.Spotlight-V100
/volumes/OD/.fseventsd
```

So far so good. But when I try negating the condition I just tested, I get an error:

```
find /volumes/OD -type d -iname ! ".*"
```

yields this error:

```
find: .*: unknown primary or operator
```

I've tried escaping the "." with "\", but I only get the same error message. I've tried removing the parenthesis, but I get same error message. What am I missing here? Should I be using another operator besides `iname`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` must precede the condition:

```
find    /volumes/OD    -type d    '!' -iname '.*'
```

That said, you shouldn't need to pipe your file-list from `find` to `rsync`; I'm sure the latter offers a way to exclude dot-folders. Maybe

```
rsync --exclude='.*' ...
```

?

Comment: Thanks for your close reading of my question. Moving the '!' in front of the condition answered it. And using `rsync --exclude='.*' ...` solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reason :
`!` is prefix of jobs such as:

```
!23
!routENTER
```

You should do :

```
find    /volumes/OD    -type d    \! -iname '.*'
```

Answer (score 1):

[ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22492297/970195) has got the right answer, but here is an alternate way of doing a search:

```
find /volumes/OD -type d -not -iname ".*"
```