# Build Directory Exclusion List Programmatically for Find Command (Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, glob

I have an array of directories to exlude from the result of my find command, something like `EXCLUDE=("foo" "bar")`.

I can run this from the interactive terminal like so:

`find . -name 'hvr.yml' -not -path "foo/*" -not -path "bar/*"`

And so i tried to build the argument up like this:

```
getServersToCheck() {

    # Build command arguments to exclude given dirs
    local exclude_command="-not -path"
    local excount=${#EXCLUDE[@]}
    for ((i=0;i<excount;i++)); do
        EXCLUDE[i]="${exclude_command} ${EXCLUDE[i]}/*"
    done

    find . -name 'hvr.yml' "${EXCLUDE[@]}"
}
```

But this results in find throwing an unknown predicate error: '-not -path foo/*'

Is there way of achieving this? When I echo the command it looks correct, but there must be some bash syntax rules that are causing this not to work how I expect.

UPDATE:

I added `\"` around the path to exclude as I read that globbing only occurs with quoted strings. xtrace shows this following:

```
find . -name hvr.yml -not -path '"foo/*"' -not -path '"bar/*"'
```

The single quotes possibly being the problem

Removing the `\"` and running with xtrace shows that the globbing is being applied in the for loop, resulting in:

```
find . -name hvr.yml -not -path "foo/fileinfoo" "foo/somethingelseinfoo" -not -path "bar/*" "bar/fileinbar" "bar/otherfilesinbar"
```

And so find is complaining about random paths being given as arguments.

Is there way to expand the EXCLUDE array and add /* to the end of each element in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an alternative solution to what I was trying to achieve by using grep:

```
EXCLUDE=("abc" "def")

getPaths() {
    local exclude_count=${#EXCLUDE[@]}
    if [ $exclude_count -eq 0 ]; then
        find . -name $FILENAME | tr '\n' ' '
        return $?
    fi

    # Concat excluded servers as grep regex
    local regex="(${EXCLUDE[0]}"
    for ((i=1;i<exclude_count;i++)); do
        regex="${regex}|${EXCLUDE[i]}"
    done
    regex="${regex})"

    find . -name $FILENAME | grep -Ev "${regex}" | tr '\n' ' '
    return $?
}
```

- If exclude is empty, this runs a normal find command.
- Otherwise, it builds up a regex for grep to filter out that ends up looking like (abc|def) for this example.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

getPaths() {
    local ROOT=$1
    local FILEFILTER=$2
    local excluded_folders=("${@:3}")
    
    local exclude_count=${#excluded_folders[@]}
    
    if [ $exclude_count -eq 0 ]; then
        find $ROOT -name $FILEFILTER
        return $?
    fi

    # Concat excluded servers as grep regex
    local regex="(${excluded_folders[0]}"
    for ((i=1;i<exclude_count;i++)); do
        regex="${regex}|${excluded_folders[i]}"
    done
    #append last )
    regex="${regex})"
    
    find $ROOT -name $FILEFILTER -print0 | grep -zZEv "${regex}" | tr '\0' '\n'
    
    return $?
}

# Define excluded folders in a string array
excluded_folders=(
  "/videos/test2" "/videos/test3"
)

inputFiles=()
readarray -t inputFiles < <(getPaths "/videos" "*.ts")
echo "found files using no exclude folders:"
echo "num files=${#inputFiles[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${inputFiles[@]}"

echo ""

echo "exclude folders:"
printf '%s\n' "${excluded_folders[@]}"

echo ""

inputFiles=()
readarray -t inputFiles < <(getPaths "/videos" "*.ts" "${excluded_folders[@]}")
echo "found files using exclude folders:"
echo "num files=${#inputFiles[@]}"
printf '%s\n' "${inputFiles[@]}"

echo ""
```

Output:

```
found files using no exclude folders:
num files=8
/videos/Pointer/Pointer_20230504_13241356.ts
/videos/Top movies/The Treasure of the Sierra Madre_20230504_14201655.ts
/videos/Top movies/Dunkirk_20230504_20252233.ts
/videos/test2/test.ts
/videos/A small light/A small light_20230504_20302130.ts
/videos/A small light/A small light_20230504_21302240.ts
/videos/test3/test3-HD.ts
/videos/test3/testje/test3-HD.ts

exclude folders:
/videos/test2
/videos/test3

found files using exclude folders:
num files=5
/videos/Pointer/Pointer_20230504_13241356.ts
/videos/Top movies/The Treasure of the Sierra Madre_20230504_14201655.ts
/videos/Top movies/Dunkirk_20230504_20252233.ts
/videos/A small light/A small light_20230504_20302130.ts
/videos/A small light/A small light_20230504_21302240.ts
```