# Combining find and ls

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, find

I'm trying to use find or grep onto the LS output.

for now, ls -l is printing tons of informations. But I only want the user associated to a filename. And the filename might be greped

Comment: So, what's the question? And why is `find` relevant? I am asking because neither of the two is very clear from what you wrote.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `find` with the `-printf` flag:

```
find . -name "a*" -printf "%u %f\n"
find . -name "M*" -printf "%u %f\n"
```

From `man find`:

> -printf format
>
> %u     File's user name, or numeric user ID if the user has no name
>
> %f     File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element).

Comment: The `-printf` option is present on [linux](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html), but is missing on [Mac os](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html). It is ok though, since OP hasn't included any `Mac os` related notes/tags.

Answer (score 3):

Most systems offer a `stat` command, which can easily produce whatever information you want about a file (or list of files). Unfortunately, the `stat` command is not standardized and the set of options vary considerably. For more information, read `man 1 stat` on your system.

On Linux, with GNU stat, you can use

```
stat -c%U file...
```

On BSD (including Mac OS X), you should be able to use

```
stat -f%Su file ...
```

(If you wanted the uid instead of the username, you would use `-c%u` or `-f%u`, respectively.)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself but my way seems way more tricky. 
I was using :

```
tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f3,9 | grep " $1.*"
```

But yours seems good. The thing is that the

```
find . -name "M*" -printf "%u %f\n"
```

also shows .git files. The topic is solved I guess, thanks for your consideration !

Comment: do not post an answer. Instead, either accept an answer (by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green) or give some feedback in comments to the answers. You can probably omit the `.git` files with a similar approach to the one described in [How can I get `find` to ignore .svn directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2314643/1983854)

Answer (score -2):

Consider adding a perl oneliner like this:

```
ll | grep user_u | perl -lane 'print "$F[2] $F[8]"'
```

-lane allow to slice the output using the space as separator, $F[2] and $F[8] are the slices of interest (first slice is $F[0])

Comment: Whilst I like perl, I'd be suggesting instead - why not use `File::Find` and more specific.

Comment: I would like that you provide us with a oneliner using this module. My solution can be easily reuse for every formated output.

Comment: You could always use `awk` instead of `perl`.  Then you don't need to remember what the `-lane` options do.

Comment: Again, [`don't parse ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Plus, suggesting use of alias (`ll`) is another no-no. AFAIK, aliases don't work in a non-interactive shell (read: shell scripts). Plus, you don't know what aliases would be defined to. I have set `alias ll='ls -alF'` Someone would  have set it to `ls -l`