# How to list all distinct extensions of tracked files in a git repository?

Tags: git, bash, grep, gitattributes

I'd like to know **all distinct extensions** of files tracked by git in a given repo, in order to create appropriate `.gitattributes` file.

Example output expected:

```
bat
gitignore
gradle
html
jar
java
js
json
md
png
properties
py
svg
webp
xml
yml
```

What command can I use for that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u
```

When you declare it as an alias, you have to escape `$1`:

```
alias gitFileExtensions="git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | perl -ne 'print \$1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u"
```

This is better than naive `find`, because:

- it excludes untracked (gitignored) files
- it excludes `.git` directory which contains usually hundreds/thousands of files and hence slows down the search

(inspired by [How can I find all of the distinct file extensions in a folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842254/how-can-i-find-all-of-the-distinct-file-extensions-in-a-folder-hierarchy))

Comment: Any reason you used double quotes around the perl part? Also maybe it'd be worth using a hash rather than piping to sort - you could add `&& !$a{$1}++` (with single quotes around the whole command) to only print the first occurrence of each result.

Comment: If I use single quotes, it prints `SCALAR(0xa031e3c)SCALAR(0xa031e3c)...`. I have to remove the escape before `$1` for it to work back. But then when I declare an alias, I have to add the escape back. Updated.

Comment: Yeah, `$` needs escaping from the shell inside double quotes. Better to just use a function in my opinion.

Comment: ad `!$a{$1}++` I tested on a huge git repo (Chrome's blink) and the speed difference is negligible in practice (0.8s vs 1.0s on my machine). I think I'll leave `sort` for readability :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to PowerShell, here is a nice one-liner which also gives you the count of how many files exist of each type:

```
$ext = @{}; git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | Get-Item | %{ $ext[$_.Extension]++ }; $ext
```

Comment: This just gives me an error. Get-Ittem : Illegal characters in path.