# How can I find all of the distinct greedy file suffixes in a folder hierarchy?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-14.04

I found a related question here:

[How can I find all of the distinct file extensions in a folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842254/how-can-i-find-all-of-the-distinct-file-extensions-in-a-folder-hierarchy)

But my case is slightly different. Using bash on Ubuntu 14.04 Linux, if I have a bunch of files like the ones below:

```
ls -1 | sort -V
fileA.foo.bar.txt.gz
fileA.foo.foo.txt.gz
fileA.xyz.bar.txt.gz
fileB.foo.bar.txt.gz
fileB.foo.foo.txt.gz
fileB.xyz.bar.txt.gz
```

I would like to know how many files of each extension I get from the *first* separator found (e.g. `\.` in the example). So it would be:

```
2 .foo.bar.txt.gz
2 .foo.foo.txt.gz
2 .xyz.bar.txt.gz
```

This is instead of the best answers that I found in the question above:

```
find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sed -e 's/.*\///' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      6 gz

find . -type f | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort | uniq -c
      6 gz
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All bash solution for files in cwd:

```
declare -A a         # declare an associative array a
for f in *.*         # loop all filenames with a .
do 
  ((a[${f#*.}]++))   # increment array elements value
done
```

Outputing counts:

```
for k in "${!a[@]}"  # loop all array keys
do 
  echo ${a[$k]} $k   # output value and key
done
1 zip
2 txt
1 txt~
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of `sed` or `perl` and use `cut`, try using:

```
find . -type f  | cut -d. -f3- | sort | uniq -c
```