# How to list of unique file types-extensions in recursive directory in Python3 in script?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to list all unique extension types in a recursive directory. I have tried the following code, it didn't print anything. It works if I put for example ".m4a". In addition, even if this code worked for ".*" it was going to list all the files but I only want the list of unique extensions. I can't list of extensions and search for them because I don't know what different file types exist.

```
for file in os.listdir(root):
    if file.endswith(".*"):
        print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

This question has been asked at [How can I find all of the distinct file extensions in a folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842254/how-can-i-find-all-of-the-distinct-file-extensions-in-a-folder-hierarchy) but it didn't help because it is for Linux machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That other question is not about Python anyway. One way to do this is to walk the path, which recursively enters subdirectories and add the file types to a set:

```
import os
exts = set(f.split('.')[-1] for dir,dirs,files in os.walk('.') for f in files if '.' in f)
```

Use `[-1]` after splitting to extract the last part, in-case the filename contains a `.`.

Use `if '.' in f` to make sure the file actually has an extension.

**Mulled it over**

and my insistence to not use `splitext` seems unwarranted, it's much cleaner:

```
import os
exts = set(os.splitext(f)[1] for dir,dirs,files in os.walk('.') for f in files)
```

which will return empty extensions for files with no extension.

Comment: One more help. In your solution in os.walk i have typed my directory manually like 'mydirectory\.'   . How can i join my directory without typing expilictly. My directory is root='my directory' in original question, thnkas in advance

Comment: Never mind, i got it, mypath=os.path.join(root,'.') worked, thanks

Comment: @kutlus If we are using `os.path` already, `os.path.splitext(file)[1]` is a less hacky way of getting the extension, though I do not use it often - it has the marked benefit of giving you "no extension" for free, making the `if` useless.

Answer (score 1):

you are only looking for files that end on (literally) `.*` - simply do:

```
import os

extensions = set()
my_root = "./"  # some dir to start in

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_root) :
    for file in files: 
        pathname, exten = os.path.splitext(file) 
        extensions.add(exten)

print(extensions) # or print(list(extensions)) if you want a list afterwards
```

Putting the extensions into a `set` makes them unique

Doku:

- [os.walk()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)
- [os.splitext()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) - includes more useful split-funtions
- [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

---

If you want a (long) 1-liner: see [kabanus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077718/7505395) - same logic but set comprehension and hence slightly faster) - not that it matters much ;o)

Answer (score 0):

The `*` character is normally interpreted by the shell and expanded by it. To access similar functionality in python, you can us the `glob` module of the standard library. Here's an example doing what you want to achieve:

```
from glob import glob

extensions = set(filename.split('.')[1] for filename in glob('*.*'))

for extension in extensions:
    print(extension)
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus, but this gave me [03,xlsx,m4a,com], i only have xlsx and m4a in my test folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like:

```python
from os import path 
from glob import glob 
root = '/tmp' 
exts = set() 
for file_ in glob(root + '/**/*.*', recursive=True): 
    exts.add(path.splitext(file_)[-1])
```

and in `exts` you will find all unique extensions

Comment: Thank you Baco, but exts gives me set().

Comment: @kutlus you can iterate over the set and access each element, the set is needed to avoid repetition of the elements.

`for ext in exts:
        print(ext)`

Do you prefer a list, you can build it from the set: `extensions_list = list(exts)`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54077718/8942966 by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner)

You can get the number of files associated with each extension using the following.

```
from collections import Counter

extensions = list(os.path.splitext(f)[1] for dir,dirs,files in os.walk('.') for f in files)

print(Counter(extensions))
```