# How git is guessing content type for purposes of end-of-line normalization?

Tags: git, normalization, gitattributes, end-of-line

According to [the documentation on .gitattributes](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes), `text` enables end-of-line normalization:

> `text`
>
> Setting the text attribute on a path enables end-of-line normalization and marks the path as a text file. End-of-line conversion takes place without guessing the content type.

I have list of extensions used in the project (`git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only | perl -ne 'print $1 if m/\.([^.\/]+)$/' | sort -u` was used to find file types - from [How can I find all of the distinct file extensions in a folder hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842254/4130619) ).

Is there way to check whatever git recognizes each extension correctly as binary/text? Is it necessary to explicitly specify type of files or is Git usually handling it well?

Comment: Git does not, in and of itself, use extensions this way. *You* can use them, by listing them in `.gitattributes` files, but by default Git just tries to determine if a file is binary or text based on the data inside the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
file --mime package.json
# text file will print:
package.json: text/plain; charset=us-ascii


# binary file will print
file --mime logo.png
logo.png: image/png; charset=binary
```

Comment: So Git is basing it behavior on `file` command? What it will be using on Windows?

Comment: simplified it, git has the same mechanism for windows as well